# How to store a JSON Feature Collection with nestjs?

Tags: geometry, nestjs, geojson

I am playing with nestjs and node-geocoder module and would like to store in my database the data received for the geocoder.
Here is what I did in ***the Interceptor*** (Let suppose all the declarations are ok):

```
provider: "opendatafrance",
};
var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);


@Injectable()
export  class PointsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
      intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {

var monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body

//Using Promise
geocoder.geocode(monaddress)
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log('res: ' + res,0);
    return next.handle().pipe(map(data => ({ res })))
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return next.handle().pipe(map(data => ({ err })))
    
  })  ;
  //console.log('result: '+result);
 return next.handle()
}
}
```

***The controller:***:

```
export class PointsController {
  constructor(private readonly pointsService: PointsService) {}

  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(PointsInterceptor)
  create(@Body() createPointDto: CreatePointDto) {
     return this.pointsService.create(createPointDto);
  }

  @Get()
  findAll() {
    return this.pointsService.findAll();
  }
}
```

***The dto***

```
export class CreatePointDto {
    readonly address: string;
    readonly type: string;
    readonly coordinates: Enumerator;
}
```

Res (the result of the geocoding function is):
[image: node-geocoder result]

Does anyone have an idea on how I can store this data?

Many thanks in advance

I used nestjs cli to generate my model and all that relates:

***Points Schema:***

```
export const PointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  address: String,
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Point'],
    default: 'Point',
    required: false,
},
coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    required: false,
},



});
```